# How to store the returned object of recursive function in array or list in matlab?

Tags: arrays, matlab, recursion

I have a recursive function that return several center coordinates(x,y) of image (for example 15 center points).In each loop print the result into MATLAB work space. how can I save them in to array instead of display in output?  (disp(s);)

```
function  [] = findGraphMhmd2(img,x1,y1,x2,y2,dir )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
fontcolor=0;
[x,y]=FindCenter(img , fontcolor , x1,y1,x2,y2 );
    %cell{1}=[-1 -1];
    %[j,k]=size(cell);
    %k=k+1;
    %cell{k}=[x y];
    s=strcat(num2str(x),',',num2str(y));
    disp(s);
    %cells=cell;
if (abs(x1-x2)<5 || abs(y1-y2)<5)
    return;
else
    if(dir)
        findGraphMhmd2(img,x1,y1,x2,y,~dir);
        findGraphMhmd2(img,x1,y,x2,y2,~dir);
    else
        findGraphMhmd2(img,x1,y1,x2,y,~dir);
        findGraphMhmd2(img,x,y1,x2,y2,~dir);
    end;
end;

end
%--------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------
function [ xc,yc ] = FindCenter(imgs , fontcolor , x1,y1,x2,y2 )
%UNTITLED Summary of this function goes here
%   Detailed explanation goes here
black=0;
sigmax=0;sigmay=0;

        for x=x1:x2
            for y=y1:y2
                if imgs(x,y)==fontcolor
                    black=black+1;
                    sigmax=x+sigmax;
                    sigmay=y+sigmay;
                    %disp(black);str=strcat(num2str(x),',',num2str(y),'=>Ex=',num2str(sigmax),'=>Ey=',num2str(sigmay));disp(str);
                end;
            end;
        end;
        if(black==0)
            xc=0;yc=0;
        else
            xc=sigmax/black;
            yc=sigmay/black;
            xc=round(xc);
            yc=round(yc);
        end;

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save stuff at the same line you use `disp`:

```
Xstorage(x,y) = sigmax;
Ystorage(x,y) = sigmay;
```

`Xstorage` will now contain your `sigmax` on the `x,y` location. If `x` and `y` are not integers, use a dummy variable as a counter, e.g. `ii=ii+1` inside the loop and use that as index to your storage variables.

In case your `x1`, `x2`, `y1`, `y2` are not integers, call your loop like:

```
xtmp = x1:stepsize:x2; %// enter desired stepsize
ytmp = x1:stepsize:x2;
for x=1:numel(xtmp)
    for y=1:numel(ytmp)
        %// calculate stuff on xtmp(x) and ytmp(y) instead of x and y
        Xstorage(x,y) = sigmax;
        Ystorage(x,y) = sigmay;
    end
end
```

`x` and `y` are now integer pointers to your arrays `xtmp` and `ytmp` which contain your actual `x` and `y` positions.

Do set the two newly created storage variables as function output as well:

```
function [xc,yc,Xstorage,Ystorage] = FindCenter(imgs , fontcolor , x1,y1,x2,y2 )
```

Comment: thanks. but how to access the Xstorage element in another function? ( what is the type of Xstorage)?

Comment: As it stands it is a 2D array, probably containing doubles. You access it, e.g. on `x=3` and `y=2` by `Xstorage(3,2)` and `Ystorage(3,2)`

Comment: Xstorage(x,y) = 1;
??? Undefined function or variable 'x'.there is no function name Xstorage

Comment: maybe lets set `Xstorage` like function output?

Comment: @hony please elaborate on what you have done and why this error occurs. Does it occur within your function? Does it occur outside your function? In the former case: please show your code, in the latter case, as Mikhail said, add it as function output.

Answer (score -1):

You may use persistent and global variables

A dirty code for factorial looks like this

```
function temp = myfactorial(x)

persistent numCalls;
global y;
persistent count;
if isempty(numCalls)
    numCalls = 0;
end
if isempty(count)
    count = 0;
end
if (x==0);
    temp = 1;
    disp([mfilename ' recursed ' num2str(numCalls) ' times.'])
     numCalls = 0;
else
    numCalls = numCalls+1;
    temp= x*myfactorial(x-1);
    count=count+1;
    y(count) =temp;
end
```

Make sure to clear variables after each use.

Comment: I strongly believe that the use of global variables is bad programming. It leads to unknown errors due to the involuntary modifications of the value and encourages bad habits in structuring code

Comment: Sorry but I think I didn't use global variables in my code!

Comment: yes, this is my first question about this . and then i find my function. but i have problem with it. http://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/54942607?noredirect=1